# git fetch is not fetching changes that are present in remote specified

Tags: git, github

I have added github remote to my git repository using:

```
git remote add --mirror=push github repository_path.git
```

I am trying to fetch from remote using:

```
git fetch github
```

where, `github` is remote I have added in previous step.

I tried to git fetch for two repositories, in case of first repo, it is able to fetch changes that are present in remote. But in case of second repo git fetch is not able to fetch changes that are present in remote.

The difference between both repositories is, the repository in which fetch is working is created by me, and repository in which fetch is not working is created by other user, but I have permission to do pull and push in that repository

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: What are the errors for the fetch for the second repository?

Comment: No error, it's just showing :Fetching github
From my-repo-name
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD

Comment: Can you share these repos so we are able to reproduce the behavior? If so, please update your question accordingly.

Comment: sorry @ckruczek I am not authorized to share those repos.

Comment: try git fetch github --verbose and let us know the result, are you using ssh or https

Comment: git fetch github --verbose is showing: Fetching github From my-repo-name * branch HEAD -> FETCH_HEAD. I am using https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR: `--mirror=push` defeated you

You probably did not want that option.  It's not at all clear what options, if any, you *did* want.

## Discussion: commits and refspecs

First (though not so important here), `git fetch` fetches *commits*, not changes.  The (Git-specific) difference between a *commit* and a "change" is that a commit is a snapshot: a complete copy of a work-tree (or more precisely, the parts of the work-tree that were in the index at the time the commit was made).  To turn a snapshot into a change, you must *compare* (i.e., `git diff`) it against some other snapshot.  (And in fact, this is not quite accurate either: `git fetch` fetches *objects*, which include commits, but also include annotated tags, trees, and blobs.  In general, though, we're mostly concerned with the commits.)

The most important part here, though, is this: the *set of commits* (and other objects) that `git fetch` fetches is controlled by *refspecs*.  A refspec, **in its second-simplest form,** looks like this:

```
master:origin/master
refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/foo/*
```

These would be typical fetch refspecs for a remote named `origin` or `foo`.  Yours is named `github`, so you might want, e.g.:

```
refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/github/*
```

as your default refspec.  This tells *your* Git that, when the *other* Git—the foreign Git you are calling up over the Internet-phone, at the URL you specified earlier—offers `refs/heads/master`, `refs/heads/branch`, and `refs/notes/commits`, *your* Git should take it up on its `master` and `branch` branches, and ignore the `commits` notes.

The left hand side of each colon-separated pair is the name you would like your Git to match.  You have no control over what their Git *offers*, but you have complete control over what you *take* (i.e., match).

The right hand side is the name you would like your Git to use in *your* repository.  As you can see here, you do not have to use the same name that the other Git uses.  You *can* use the same name, if that's what you want, but you do not *have* to, and usually you do not *want* to.  Usually, you want to take *their* branch names, such as their `master`, and *rename* them to be your *remote-tracking branch names*: `origin/master`, for instance.

I mentioned above that this is the *second* simplest form of refspec.  The simplest is one without a colon, such as `master`.  **If you use this colon-free form of refspec, `git fetch` does not give the fetched objects any name in your repository.**  This is what you are seeing.

(This is once again not 100% accurate: *any* `git fetch` writes to `FETCH_HEAD`.  However, `FETCH_HEAD` is a remarkably temporary name.  Specifically, the very next `git fetch` overwrites it, since *any* `git fetch` writes to `FETCH_HEAD`.  So it might as well be "no name": it's only good until the next fetch.  That's all that the original `git pull` script needed, back when `git fetch` was merely plumbing for the user-oriented `pull` script, before "remotes" were invented in the first place.  But it's no good these days, when we want our remote-tracking branches updated.)

#### Why `git fetch` needs some default refspecs

If you run `git fetch remote`, you are running it with *no* refspec arguments.  In this case, `git fetch` looks up the *default* refspecs in your Git configuration.  Normally, `git remote add` sets these up for you:

```
$ git remote add foo ssh://host.dom.ain/path/to/repo.git
```

creates `remote "foo"` with two configured items:

```
$ git config --get remote.foo.url
ssh://host.dom.ain/path/to/repo.git
$ git config --get-all remote.foo.fetch
refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/foo/*
```

(We should always use `--get-all` here, in case there is more than one configured `fetch` line, but in fact `git remote add` only sets up one.)

You used `git remote add --mirror=push`, though, and that *changes* what `git remote add` sets up for the new remote.  Instead of adding `remote.foo.fetch` set to `refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/foo/*`, it adds `remote.foo.mirror` set to `true`:

```
$ git config --get-regexp '^remote\.foo\.'
remote.foo.url ssh://host.dom.ain/path/to/repo.git
remote.foo.mirror true
```

In particular, **there are no `remote.foo.fetch` entries.**

(This `--get-regexp` lets us examine everything under a `[remote "foo"]` section.  It is an alternative to `--get-all` that accepts an arbitrary regular expression, and we gave it one matching `remote.foo.` with a left anchor `^` and the two dot characters quoted to make sure they match a literal dot rather than any single character.  Note that regular expressions are different from, and more powerful than, shell style globs: the `fetch` refspecs are shell-style globs, not regular expressions.  None of this is stuff you *need* to know, it's just useful side information.)

#### Without refspecs, `git fetch` is hamstrung

Without either a command-line refspec:

```
git fetch github 'refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/github/*'
```

or a default `remote.github.fetch`, `git fetch` falls back on a weak and flimsy built-in default.  It asks the *other* Git: "What's your most significant branch?  Specifically, what commit is your `HEAD`?"  It then fetches that commit (and its history as needed), and calls that `FETCH_HEAD`, in *your* repository:

```
From <url>
 * branch                HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

You now have the time from now until your next `git fetch` to do something with `FETCH_HEAD`.

#### Figure out why you used `--mirror=push`, then come up with the option you really want

Setting `remote.remote.mirror` to `true` has the same effect as specifying `--mirror` on the command line: it force-pushes *all* local refs to a ref of the same name on the remote, as if you used `+refs/*:refs/*`.<sup>1</sup>  But if the remote is a push mirror when compared to the local repository, you probably never want to fetch from it at all.  (In other words, this combination—push mirror, but fetch-able—makes no sense.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that push refspecs differ somewhat from fetch refspecs.  Both use the same syntax: an optional force flag, a source ref name or single-asterisk glob pattern, a colon, and a destination ref name or similar glob pattern.  The source and destinations are reversed, though: for fetching, the source is the remote repository / other Git, while for pushing, the source is the local repository / our Git.  The meaning of a missing destination differs as well: for fetch, a missing destination means *use only `FETCH_HEAD`*, but for push, a missing destination means *use the same name*, e.g., `git push master` means *push (our) master to (their) master*.  Finally, fetch does not allow an empty source, but push does: that means *ask the remote Git to delete the reference entirely*.